# Postgresql - reference selected values inside subqueries

Tags: postgresql

you can do something like below in MySQL easily:

```
Select 
@date := `Date`,
(Select sum(High) From tsdata where `Date` = @date) As MySum
From sometable Where type = 'A'
```

How can I do something similar in postgres?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you add an example? with the desired result. Sometimes it is better to build a new query rather than try to find code alternatives.

Comment: Hi Dan, I have no specific output in mind, just will need to write a query with few sub-queries that need to use selected columns as variables inside aggregate (sum, avg, etc) subqueries. Thanks

Comment: You can do something like that with `Window Functions` or the use of `WITH` in PostgreSQL. Also you can create a PL with `DO`... you have many options.... but it would be best to have an example to give you a more adequate answer

Comment: Thanks Dan, I did some reading and went with WITH.But this lack of ability to declare & assign variables within the query is bit shocking :). Thanks again.

Comment: You can use `DO`to declare variables... but there are far better ways to do queries in PostgreSQL. Windows Functions are really great to handle aggregation functions.